# Actionbar background

Tags: android, android-actionbar

it's possible that change action-bar background with custom image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i try this code & work right :

```
BitmapDrawable bg =(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher); // get the image as bitmap drawable
bg.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.CLAMP); // set the TileMode.
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

You can set background drawables using themes